# is it possible to use Eigen with c?

Tags: c, eigen

I don't know very much about template programming, and I currently use gsl.  I'm interested in seeing if Eigen can be use in C.  Has anybody used Eigen in C before? Is there something I can test to find out if it will be easy?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since Eigen is a C++ template library, it cannot be directly used with C.

Hypothetically, one could wrap the C++ templates into a C API, and use that. However, that's bound to involve a lot of work and would strike me as a bit pointless (one might as well use existing C libraries for linear algebra).

Comment: N.B.: Eigen does provide a BLAS and Lapack interface (which is callable from C or Fortran)

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK, Eigen is a template-only library.  C doesn't support templates.  So without writing a bunch of wrapper functions that expose a C-style interface, no.